# asp Dot net core on Apache Linux ,intranet user identify like windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-core, windows-authentication

Asp Dot net 2 core web application when deployed in Linux - Apache server .
Enable windows authentication in Vs solution, but when deployed on Linux how to identify system logged in user, like "internet information server" window authentication.
Kindly suggest i tried deployed in Linux and user.identity.name is null.
how to achieve in Linux.

Comment: There is no Linux-equivalent of Windows Auth.

Comment: How to identify the logged in user ,when we deploy dotnet core in Apache server.

Comment: any update please any one, just i need to make work user.Identity.Name to work in Apache ,asp Dot net Core. is any setting needs to be done in Linux like IIS.Please update

Comment: *It's not possible.*

Comment: Then how to pick logged in user .any suggestions?